# Python datetime difference between .localize and tzinfo

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

Why do these two lines produce different results?

```python
>>> import pytz
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> local_tz = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")

>>> d1 = local_tz.localize(datetime(2015, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)) # line 1
>>> d2 = datetime(2015, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, local_tz) # line 2
>>> d1 == d2
False
```

What's the reason for the difference, and which should I use to localize a datetime?

Comment: See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359540/why-doesnt-pytz-localize-produce-a-datetime-object-with-tzinfo-matching-the-t).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create `d2 = datetime(2015, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, local_tz)`, it does not handle daylight saving time (DST) correctly. `local_tz.localize()` does.

`d1` is

```python
>>> local_tz.localize(datetime(2015, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
datetime.datetime(
    2015, 8, 1, 0, 0, 
    tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>
)
```

`d2` is

```python
>>> datetime(2015, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, local_tz)
datetime.datetime(
    2015, 8, 1, 0, 0, 
    tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' LMT-1 day, 16:07:00 STD>
)
```

You can see that they are not representing the same time.

`d2` way is fine if you are going to work with UTC. UTC does not have daylight saving time (DST) transitions to deal with.

**The correct way to handle timezone is to use `local_tz.localize()` to support daylight saving time (DST)**

More information and additional examples can be found here:
http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic

Comment: So d1 is the more appropriate and correct way to localize times?

Comment: @Nick yep, it is.