# Difference between datetime.combine() and pytz.localize()

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am a bit puzzled by the following behavior. Suppose I use [`datetime.combine()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) to construct a timezone-aware object:

```
>>> date
datetime.date(2018, 10, 17)
>>> time
datetime.time(6, 0)
>>> tz
<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' LMT+0:53:00 STD>
>>> datetime.combine(date, time, tzinfo=tz)
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 17, 6, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' LMT+0:53:00 STD>)
```

or I use [`pytz.localize()`](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) to do the same:

```
>>> tz.localize(datetime.combine(date, time))
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 17, 6, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

Note how the [`tzinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.tzinfo)’s timezone name and offset have changed. I am unable to find a proper documentation for that behavior. The `pytz` documentation says

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors “does not work” with pytz for many timezones.

So what exactly is going on here? (Somewhat related questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460236/python-datetime-difference-between-localize-and-tzinfo) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359540/why-doesnt-pytz-localize-produce-a-datetime-object-with-tzinfo-matching-the-t).)

Answer (score 10):

You just found out (again) that you should never directly add timezone information when creating timezone-aware datetimes. Always use `tz.localize()`.

The problem you are seeing is because `datetime.combine` doesn't adjust the `tzinfo` object to the actual datetime. It still assumes the timezone information of the first valid date in this timezone, which was in the late 1800's and happened to be `0:53:00` off from UTC.

Comment: Thanks. Neither the Python documentation nor the pytz documentation states that, as far as I can see. Hence my question. I’m tempted to label this as a bug in the Python libs?

Comment: It's not totally obvious, but that's mostly because very little about timezones is obvious. Since you are passing a timezone instance that doesn't come from the stdlib, and the stdlib timezones only handle simple timezones without transitions where this is not an issue, then I think it's reasonable that you refer to the documentation of `pytz`, where the correct usage is quite clear. It starts by stating two correct ways to localize datetimes, and then proceeds to discourage what you just did :-)

Comment: Well, `tzinfo=…` _does_ work for some timezones, e.g. it’s safe apparently to pass `tzinfo=pytz.utc`. That too is mentioned somewhere in the `pytz` documentation, but again, I’d like to understand _why_ this happens. Your initial explanation of a “first valid date” does make sense though.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! To explain my own confusion: The `pytz` documentation says to avoid setting `tzinfo` when creating a `datetime.datetime`, but it doesn't really say anything about not using `combine()` with a localized `datetime.time` instance (it never mentions `datetime.time` at all).  I could have guessed to do it this way, though I wouldn't have known if it is recommended...  Seeing this question and your answer is helpful!