# pytz timezone has the wrong offset during daylight saving time

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I have a problem with pytz and daylight saving time. When I use the timezone `Europe/Berlin`, it always uses the timezone offset without DST.

Minimal example:

```
print(repr(pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")))
<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CET+1:00:00 STD>
# Should probably be something like <DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CET+2:00:00 DST>

# Usage
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime
datetime_now = timezone.now()
print(my_time)
# Result: 00:00:00
print(datetime.combine(datetime_now, my_time, tzinfo=timezone.get_current_timezone()))
# Result: 2020-04-04 00:00:00+01:00, should be 2020-04-04 00:00:00+02:00
```

The minimal example for my use case would be an alarm clock. The user sets the clock to `06:00` (without thinking about timezones) and the clock should ring at `06:00` in the current timezone, i.e., `06:00+02` when it's DST and `06:00+01` otherwise for `Europe/Berlin`.

---

The implementation is a Django model using `django.models.TimeField` for the non-aware Time (e.g. `06:00`) and I want to compare it to the current time and other TimeFields by creating a datetime object that has the current date and the time storted in the `TimeField`.

I am open to different suggestions about time objects (e.g using or not using `django.utils.timezone`) as long as I can create datetime objects that I can compare to each other and increment / decrement with timedelta objects (or some similar method).

---

Another minimal example (with Django only for getting the current timezone):

```
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

tz = timezone.get_current_timezone()
time_now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz)
clock_time = datetime.time(1,2)
combined_time = datetime.combine(time_now, clock_time, tzinfo=tz)
print(tz)
print(time)
print(time_now)
print(combined_time)
```

results in

```
Europe/Berlin
01:02:00
2020-04-12 18:50:11.934754+02:00
2020-04-12 01:02:00+01:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `tzinfo` when building timezone-aware datetimes. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52733868/difference-between-datetime-combine-and-pytz-localize).

Since you're using Django, assuming `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'`, we can use [`make_aware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware):

```py
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime, time

# Get a localized datetime so that .combine gets the local date
local_now = timezone.localtime()
# localtime() is a shortcut for
# timezone.now().astimezone(timezone.get_current_timezone())

clock_time = time(1, 2)
combined_time = timezone.make_aware(datetime.combine(local_now, clock_time))
print(combined_time)
```

It will print

```
2020-04-21 01:02:00+02:00
```

Alternatively, use the [`localize` function in pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) (which is used in the [`make_aware` function definition](https://github.com/django/django/blob/290eb987644c31aabcfd52d81bd5adcf7a1972aa/django/utils/timezone.py#L228) anyways, but check the details below):

```py
tz = timezone.get_current_timezone()  # or pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
combined_time = tz.localize(datetime.combine(local_now, clock_time))
# 2020-04-21 01:02:00+02:00
```

If you see the [Django code for timezone.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/timezone.py), these functions are basically pytz wrappers. In particular, check the definitions for `make_aware`, `localtime` and `now`.

There's one particular difference between `make_aware` and `localize`, though. Both accept the argument `is_dst`, but for Django's `make_aware` it's `None` by default, while it's [`False` for pytz](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/7b1a844c8ecf2996142ac0eb32201b676e9dcb9a/src/pytz/tzinfo.py#L112). This difference matters in your case **if a user writes a time that doesn't exist, or happens twice, when entering DST**. Here, having `is_dst=None` will make the function raise `NonExistentTimeError` or `AmbiguousTimeError`, respectively. Otherwise, [a boolean value will cause it to guess](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#problems-with-localtime).

---

**Example:**
In `Europe/Berlin` this year, the clock went forward one hour on March 29, 2:00 am. Therefore, 2:30 am didn't happen in local time. Python treats this input depending on `is_dst`:

```py
time_doesnt_exist = datetime(2020, 3, 29, 2, 30, 0)
print(tz.localize(time_doesnt_exist, is_dst=None))
# Raises NonExistentTimeError
print(tz.localize(time_doesnt_exist, is_dst=True))
2020-03-29 02:30:00+02:00
print(tz.localize(time_doesnt_exist, is_dst=False))
2020-03-29 02:30:00+01:00
```

---

To get the exception-raising behavior with `localize`:

```py
combined_time = tz.localize(datetime.combine(local_now, clock_time), is_dst=None)
```

To make `make_aware` not raise instead:

```py
combined_time = timezone.make_aware(
  datetime.combine(local_now, clock_time),
  is_dst=False,  # Or True...
)
```

---

### A word of caution: Arithmetic on localized time

Doing arithmetic on localized datetimes requires [calling `normalize`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) as a workaround for DST issues, when they arise

```py
time_before_dst = datetime(2020, 3, 29, 1, 50, 0)
local_time_before_dst = tz.localize(time_before_dst) 
new_time = local_time_before_dst + timedelta(minutes=40)
print(new_time)
# 2020-03-29 02:30:00+01:00
# Didn't switch to DST!
print(tz.normalize(new_time))
# 2020-03-29 03:30:00+02:00
# Correctly did the switch
```

Comment: Is it right to use `tz.localize(datetime.combine(my_datetime_obj, time(1, 2)))` for the `localize` variant using `localize` *after* `combine` (because `combine` does not support timezones)? Maybe you could add a full example for how to use it in the best way to your post.

Comment: @allo It actually wasn't right. The localization needs to happen before the `combine` so that the clock time is inserted into the correct date. Just fixed it and added details on DST handling too