# Why do I get the offset 0:53 for timezone Europe/Berlin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, pytz

### Example Code

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pytz

tzstring = 'Europe/Berlin'
t1 = datetime(2016, 6, 16, 2, 0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone(tzstring))
t2 = datetime(2016, 6, 16, 2, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone(tzstring))
```

### Observed

```
print(t1): 2016-06-16 02:00:00+00:53
print(t2): 2016-06-16 04:00:00+02:00
```

### Expected

```
print(t1): 2016-06-16 04:00:00+02:00  # does not match expectation
print(t2): 2016-06-16 04:00:00+02:00  # matches expectation
```

### Question

Can somebody please explain that to me?

### Other questions:

- [Why doesn't pytz localize() produce a datetime object with tzinfo matching the tz object that localized it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24370601/562769) only asks for an explanation to "where in the code does it come from". My question is more in the direction: "Why is it that off?" - so likely a bit of history will be in an answer that I accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't pytz localize() produce a datetime object with tzinfo matching the tz object that localized it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359540/why-doesnt-pytz-localize-produce-a-datetime-object-with-tzinfo-matching-the-t)

Comment: The other answer also shows why it's that value: [LMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time). And I really don't see the benefit to large section titles in such a simple question.

Comment: The reason its like that isn't really a programming question. It has to do with the [history of german timezones](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/OFD3976F87.F787752A-ONC1257B67.00473B00-C1257B67.00482D32%40ppi.de).

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge Ah, nice! [This Wiki article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesetz_betreffend_die_Einführung_einer_einheitlichen_Zeitbestimmung) goes in the right direction! What I still miss there is how the local time was / is calculated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't like to say I can explain it as such, but it *is* documented to not work. From the [pytz home page](https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic):

> This library only supports two ways of building a localized time. The first is to use the `localize()` method provided by the pytz library. This is used to localize a naive datetime (datetime with no timezone information)
>
> *(Example)*
>
> The second way of building a localized time is by converting an existing localized time using the standard `astimezone()` method.
>
> *(Example)*
>
> **Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors 'does not work' with pytz for many timezones.**
>
> ```
> >>> datetime(2002, 10, 27, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=amsterdam).strftime(fmt)
> '2002-10-27 12:00:00 LMT+0020'
> ```
>
> It is safe for timezones without daylight saving transitions though, such as UTC

I suspect the representation of time zones in pytz is just incompatible with what the datetime constructor uses.

Rather than chase the exact details, I suspect it's more practical just to accept it doesn't work and use the alternatives suggested.

Comment: (The answer from the question I marked this question as a duplicate of explains it)

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge That answer might be clear to you, but it certainly is not for me. Yes, it is in the tz data sources. But why is it like that?