# Python dates with timezone, strange differences between UTC and CET

Tags: python, timezone, timezone-offset, pytz

I'm not sure why, I thought the time difference between CET and UTC was one hour. Now I am debugging code and have this:

```
(Pdb++) server_date
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 16, 1, 15, 58, 643927, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Ber
lin' LMT+0:53:00 STD>)

utc_date = server_date.astimezone(pytz.utc)

(Pdb++) utc_date
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 16, 0, 22, 58, 643927, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Why is Berlin 53min from UTC and not one hour? I'm confused. Is this something with the intermediate timezones like 5:45 for random countries?
What did I miss in geography class, lol...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get the offset 0:53 for timezone Europe/Berlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50443447/1431750)

Comment: Also this one: [Why doesn't pytz localize() produce a datetime object with tzinfo matching the tz object that localized it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24370601/1431750)

Comment: I’m a way of blows my mind a bit that there are historic differences... thanks for the links, I have to dig deeper into that...