# Why is pytz US/Eastern -0456 and not -0500

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

Working with pytz in Python. I have a datetime objects that I am trying to convert to different timezones. When printing the UTC Offset, I am not getting a -0500. What's the reason for this?

```py
original_utc = datetime.datetime(1900,6,6,10,40, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC'))

in_eastern = lesson.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))



print("UTC time: ", original_utc.strftime("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S %Z %z"))
print("----------")
print("EST time", in_eastern.strftime("%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S %Z %z"))
```

Gives me:

```
UTC time:  1900:06:06 10:40:00 UTC +0000
----------
EST time 1900:06:06 05:44:00 LMT -0456
```

Comment: Something to do with the year being 1900?

Comment: Maybe accumulated leap seconds?

Comment: Seems to stop doing that on 1901-12-14... 13th still has the weird offset. | Now found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69318097/why-is-there-a-4-minute-timezone-shift-between-ny-utc-on-1901-12-14

Comment: Because that’s what the offset from UTC was at the time.